# Summing integer value in ZF2 query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, group-by, sum

I have a query which basically picks out all of the points in my mysql table. I'm using the Zend Framework 2 and the query basically looks like this:

```
public function GetFiveUsersWithHighestPoints($brandId,$startDate, $endDate)
    {
        $select = new Select();
        $select->from(array("h" => $this->table));
        $select->columns(array(
            "id",
            "userId",
            "type",
            "points",
            "missionId",
            "rewardId",
            "brandId",
            "goodsId",
            "time",
        ));
        $select->order("h.points desc");
        $where = new Where();
        $select->join(array("m" => "missions"), "h.missionId = m.id", array("missionId" => "id", "missionName" => "title", "missionAction" => "action"), Select::JOIN_LEFT);
        if (!empty($journeyId)) {
            $where->equalTo("m.journeyId", $journeyId);
        } else {
            $select->join(array("r" => "rewards"), "h.rewardId = r.id", array("rewardId" => "id", "rewardName" => "name"), Select::JOIN_LEFT);
        }
        $where->notEqualTo("h.points", 0);
        $where->equalTo("h.brandId", $brandId);
        $where->between("h.time", $startDate, $endDate);
        //分页代码块。固定用法
        $select->where($where);
        return $this->historyTable->selectWith($select)->toArray();
    }
```

Now what I would like to do is that all of the points are grouped by userid, which would basically correspond to the fact how many points each user has made in the given time span... How can I do sum all of the points per UserId, so that I get something like this:

1. UserId 26 => 100 points
2. UserId 27 => 200 points

etc. etc.

I'm quite new to writing queries in Zend Framework 2 and I'm not sure what am I supposed to do next...

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a `SUM()` column with a `GROUP BY`, something like:

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;

// Include a SUM() expression
$select->cols([

    // Include existing columns
    // etc...

    // Add a SUM col
    'pointsCount' => new Expression('SUM(h.points)'),

]);

// Add a GROUP BY
$select->group('h.userId');
```

The per-user sum of points that you seek should then accessible in each result row under the name `pointsCount`.